# Persisting JSONStore data in local storage across application restarts?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

JSONStore provides us with a great way to sync data with a server and track changes a user makes while offline. However, since JSONStore data is only in memory, any changes are lost if the user stops the application or restarts their device.

It looks like the Cordova storage API might be part of the solution, but I don't see a clear way that we can persist and retrieve the JSONStore data with it.

Answer (score 3):

> JSONStore data is only in memory.

That is incorrect, unless you are talking about another JSONStore. Data will be persisted unless the application is uninstalled from the device or there's a call to: [destroy](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_destroy.html), [remove](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_remove.html), [erase](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_erase.html) or [removeCollection](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_removecollection.html). Take a look at the [Getting Started Modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#mobile-client-development) (7.9, 7.10, 7.11 and 7.12) and [IBM InfoCenter documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_class_wl_jsonstore.html) for more details.

Try the following code snippet:

```
var c = WL.JSONStore.initCollection('customers', {name: 'string'}, {onSuccess: function(){
    c.add({name: 'helloworld'}, {onSuccess: function(){
        c.findAll({onSuccess: function (res) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
        }})
    }});
}});
```

I have omitted the failure callbacks for brevity. Every time you run the application it will store a new 'helloworld' document. You can restart the application and the data will still be there. You can read more about the API methods I used here: [initCollection](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_initcollection.html), [add](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_add.html), [findAll](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_findall.html).

> Maybe there is a method we should check for existing data so we don't
>   erase it somehow?

You can call [count](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_count.html) to see how much data is inside a JSONStore collection.

If you want to get data from your backend you need to create a Worklight Adapter and link it to your collection and then need to call [load](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_load.html). To send data back to your backend you can call [push](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_jsonstore_push.html). This is better explained in the [Getting Started Modules](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/), specifically: [Module 7.11 - JSONStore with Synchronization](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v505/Module_07_11_-_JSONStore_with_Sync.pdf).

As a side note, make sure you call JSONStore after the `ondeviceready` event has fired. It's safe you make JSONStore calls inside the `wlCommonInit` function. Make sure you test on an Android or iOS platform (devices or emulators/simulators). It won't work on the Mobile Browser Simulator or on any Web Browser.

Answer (score 2):

The JSONStore is saved as a file in the device local storage. The JSONStore is persistent.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? We built a demo app that works to go offline and then syncs data edits back to the server when reconnected. However an app restart kills the data. Maybe there is a method we should check for existing data so we don't erase it somehow?

Thanks!

Comment: @Handly: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15104252/186909) for the method to check for existing data.

Answer (score -3):

Take a look at [PhoneGap Storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage). All those methods should be available in Worklight through the Cordova library.